# Update partitioned tables in for loop

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to rename a table that has partitions, add some columns and copy the data from existing columns to the new ones with an update.

The problem I face is that I get an out of memory exception while updating after 2000 seconds.

I would like to still updates my tables, but in a for loop or any other better solution.
Instead of updating x that contains x1, x2, x3, x4. I would like to update x1, then when it's done x2, etc.

How may I do that in an efficient way? Thank you

```
do $$
  declare
    arow record;
    curtable varchar(50);
  begin
    IF EXISTS (SELECT relname FROM pg_class WHERE relname='events') THEN
        -- DO STUFF HERE
        
        -- DROP OLD TRIGGER
        DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS events_partition_trigger ON events;
        ALTER SEQUENCE IF EXISTS events_id_seq RENAME TO fact_entriesexits_id_seq;
        -- Rename events table to fact_entriesexits
        ALTER TABLE events RENAME TO fact_entriesexits;

        -- Add new columns
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN facilitykey integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN systeminterfacekey integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN devicekey integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN datekey integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN timekey integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN tickettypekey integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN eventtypekey integer; 
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN manufacturerkey integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN devicetype integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN licenseplate character varying(100);
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN licenseplatekey integer;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN cardnumber character varying(100);
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN eventdate timestamp without time zone;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN dateinserted timestamp without time zone;
        ALTER TABLE fact_entriesexits ADD COLUMN etlsource integer;

    

        -- Rename events_yyyy_mm to fact_entriesexits_yyyymm
        for arow in
          SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' and table_name like 'events_%'
        loop
          curtable := arow.table_name;
          RAISE NOTICE 'Calling table(%)', curtable;
          --Rename
          execute ('ALTER TABLE ' || curtable ||' RENAME TO fact_entriesexits_' || replace(right(curtable, 8), '_', ''));
          --Add idx on datekey
          execute('CREATE INDEX idx_fact_entriesexits_' || replace(right(curtable, 8), '_', '') || ' ON fact_entriesexits_' || replace(right(curtable, 8), '_', '') || ' ( datekey )');
        end loop;
        -- END RENAME PARTITION
        
        

        -- Map the new surrogate keys 
        Update fact_entriesexits e
        set  datekey = cast(to_char((event_time)::TIMESTAMP,'yyyymmdd') as integer),
             timekey = cast(to_char((event_time)::TIMESTAMP,'hhmiss') as integer),
             dateinserted = odb_created_at,
             devicetype = device_type,
             cardnumber = card_nr,
             manufacturerkey = 
                 case when manufacturer like '%DESIGNA%' THEN 2 
                 WHEN manufacturer like '%SKIDAT%' THEN 3
                 WHEN manufacturer like '%IPCP%' THEN 1  
                 WHEN manufacturer like '%SCHEIDT%' THEN 4 END,
             eventdate = event_time;


        -- Update to 2.0 Mapping
        Update fact_entriesexits e  set  ticket_type    = 14 where ticket_type in (2,15);
        Update fact_entriesexits e  set  ticket_type  = 41 where ticket_type = 8;
        Update fact_entriesexits e  set  ticket_type  = 9  where ticket_type = 30;
        Update fact_entriesexits e  set  ticket_type  = 21 where ticket_type = 20;
        Update fact_entriesexits e  set  ticket_type  = 33 where ticket_type = 18;
        


        -- SET ticket type, eventtype surrogate keys
        Update fact_entriesexits e  set  tickettypekey   = dt.key  from dim_tickettype dt 
        where dt.tickettypeid = e.ticket_type and event_time >= dt.scd_start AND (event_time < dt.scd_end OR dt.scd_end IS NULL);
        
        Update fact_entriesexits e  set  eventtypekey = et.key from dim_eventtype et
        where et.eventtypeid = e.event_type and event_time >= et.scd_start AND (event_time < et.scd_end OR et.scd_end IS NULL);
        
        Update fact_entriesexits e  set  facilitykey  = et.key from dim_facility et
        where et.facilityid = e.carpark_id and event_time >= et.scd_start AND (event_time < et.scd_end OR et.scd_end IS NULL);
```

---

**UPDATE**

After trying to adjust my postgres settings as suggested:

- shared_buffers from 124 to 64mb
- work_mem from 4 to 1mb
- maintenance_work_mem from 64 to 10mb

I could see that postgres decreased my local space from 90gb to 50gb before crashing.

The query did run a bit longer, but I got the same error. I tried to reduce the settings even more but didn't help.
Here's a part of the log file:

```
TopMemoryContext: 215296 total in 11 blocks; 12968 free (14 chunks); 202328 used
  Btree proof lookup cache: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 552 free (0 chunks); 7640 used
  CFuncHash: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 552 free (0 chunks); 7640 used
  Rendezvous variable hash: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 552 free (0 chunks); 7640 used
  PLpgSQL function hash: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 2616 free (0 chunks); 5576 used
  TopTransactionContext: 4207160 total in 11 blocks; 1773336 free (21 chunks); 2433824 used
    SPI Exec: 1048576 total in 8 blocks; 232856 free (5 chunks); 815720 used
      ExecutorState: 34413231712 total in 4116 blocks; 203584 free (3461 chunks); 34413028128 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7856 free (0 chunks); 336 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7808 free (1 chunks); 384 used
    SPI Proc: 139264 total in 5 blocks; 11656 free (3 chunks); 127608 used
      PLpgSQL per-statement data: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
      expanded record: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7240 free (1 chunks); 952 used
      PLpgSQL private cast cache: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 1576 free (0 chunks); 6616 used
      ExecutorState: 16384 total in 2 blocks; 3840 free (3 chunks); 12544 used
        ExprContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (0 chunks); 264 used
      PL/pgSQL inline code context: 65536 total in 4 blocks; 30336 free (2 chunks); 35200 used
    Combo CIDs: 65536 total in 4 blocks; 26608 free (9 chunks); 38928 used
  Prepared Queries: 16384 total in 2 blocks; 6656 free (3 chunks); 9728 used
  Type information cache: 24376 total in 2 blocks; 2616 free (0 chunks); 21760 used
  TableSpace cache: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 2088 free (0 chunks); 6104 used
  Operator lookup cache: 24576 total in 2 blocks; 10752 free (3 chunks); 13824 used
  pgstat TabStatusArray lookup hash table: 32768 total in 3 blocks; 9448 free (5 chunks); 23320 used
  RowDescriptionContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 3816 free (1 chunks); 4376 used
  MessageContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 6744 free (0 chunks); 1448 used
  Operator class cache: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 552 free (0 chunks); 7640 used
  smgr relation table: 65536 total in 4 blocks; 12544 free (14 chunks); 52992 used
  TransactionAbortContext: 32768 total in 1 blocks; 32504 free (0 chunks); 264 used
  Portal hash: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 552 free (0 chunks); 7640 used
  TopPortalContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7656 free (1 chunks); 536 used
    PortalContext: 14168 total in 5 blocks; 3040 free (10 chunks); 11128 used: <unnamed>
  Relcache by OID: 32768 total in 3 blocks; 5304 free (6 chunks); 27464 used
  CacheMemoryContext: 8388608 total in 11 blocks; 1432944 free (1 chunks); 6955664 used
    CachedPlan: 525312 total in 10 blocks; 197920 free (0 chunks); 327392 used: Update fact_entriesexits e   set  datekey = cast(to_char((event_time)::TIMESTAMP,'yyyymmdd') as inte...
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 528 free (1 chunks); 1520 used: pg_toast_2619_index
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2022_02
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2022_01
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_12
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_11
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_10
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_09
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_08
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2021_07
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_07
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2021_07
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2021_06
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_06
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2021_06
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2021_05
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_05
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2021_05
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2021_04
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_04
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2021_04
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2021_03
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_03
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2021_03
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2021_02
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_02
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2021_02
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2021_01
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2021_01
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2021_01
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_12
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_12
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_12
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_11
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_11
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_11
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_10
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_10
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_10
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_09
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_09
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_09
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_08
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_08
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_08
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_07
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_07
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_07
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_06
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_06
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_06
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_05
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_05
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_05
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_04
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_04
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_04
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_03
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_03
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_03
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 608 free (1 chunks); 1440 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_02
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 904 free (0 chunks); 1144 used: idx_events_2020_02
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1840 free (2 chunks); 3512 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_02
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2020_01
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2020_01
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2020_01
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_12
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_12
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_12
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_11
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_11
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_11
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_10
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_10
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_10
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_09
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_09
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_09
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_08
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_08
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_08
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_07
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_07
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_07
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_06
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_06
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_06
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_05
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_05
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_05
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_04
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_04
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_04
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_03
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_03
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_03
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_02
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 824 free (0 chunks); 1224 used: idx_events_2019_02
    index info: 5352 total in 4 blocks; 1440 free (2 chunks); 3912 used: idx_carpark_events_2019_02
    index info: 2048 total in 2 blocks; 448 free (1 chunks); 1600 used: idx_events_manufacturer_2019_01
    336 more child contexts containing 1114912 total in 734 blocks; 354264 free (192 chunks); 760648 used
  WAL record construction: 49768 total in 2 blocks; 6360 free (0 chunks); 43408 used
  PrivateRefCount: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 1576 free (0 chunks); 6616 used
  MdSmgr: 16384 total in 2 blocks; 6120 free (0 chunks); 10264 used
  LOCALLOCK hash: 131072 total in 5 blocks; 69800 free (17 chunks); 61272 used
  Timezones: 104120 total in 2 blocks; 2616 free (0 chunks); 101504 used
  ErrorContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 7928 free (3 chunks); 264 used
Grand total: 34430438296 bytes in 5277 blocks; 5036032 free (3868 chunks); 34425402264 used
2022-02-18 02:25:26.324 CET [516] FEHLER:  Speicher aufgebraucht
2022-02-18 02:25:26.324 CET [516] DETAIL:  Fehler bei Anfrage mit Größe 40 im Speicherkontext »ExecutorState«.
2022-02-18 02:25:26.324 CET [516] ZUSAMMENHANG:  SQL-Anweisung »Update fact_entriesexits e
```

Comment: Raise `max_locks_per_transaction`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe raised it to ```max_locks_per_transaction = 1024``` and restarted Postgres. I got the same error again

Comment: What exactly is the error message, and is there a memory context dump in the log file?

Comment: ```Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Memory used up.
  Detail: error on query with gre 64 in memory context ExecutorState.```

Translated from German to English
How could I check if there is a memory context dump in the log?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting an "out of memory" error, you have to reduce the settings that determine PostgreSQL's memory consumption: `shared_buffers`, `work_mem`, `maintenance_work_mem`.

Comment: I have edited my question and added an update after trying to decrease PostgreSQL's memory consumption. The query did run a bit longer but I ended up getting the same error...

Comment: Revert the settings, it makes no sense to decrease them even beneath the default values. I still have no clue what the problem is, but you can certainly work around it by *not* doing everything in a single transaction = `DO` block. Write a shell script or something similar on the client side.